# Monitor Nginx response time with munin

Tags: nginx, monitoring, munin

Well, nginx is configured to put $request_time in it's access logs. Now I need to monitor this parameter with munin.

**Is there any existing plugin to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this munin plugin: https://github.com/arthur-debert/munin-httpresponse-plugin/blob/master/httpresponsetime